# array console.log is not using custom class toString

Tags: javascript, tostring

*Chrome 54.0.2840.71 (64-bit)*

I have an array of objects built from a custom class. If I `console.log` the array, how do I get the objects in the array to use their `toString` function without having to manually loop the array? Is this possible?

**Code** *[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6mbg6ffp/)*

```
function MyClass(value) {
  MyClass.prototype.getValue = function() {
    return value;
  }
}
MyClass.prototype.toString = function() {
    return "[MyClass: " + this.getValue() + "]";
}

var mc0 = new MyClass(0);
var mc1 = new MyClass(1);
console.log([mc0, mc1]);
```

**Current Output**

```
[MyClass, MyClass]
```

**Desired Output**

```
[[MyClass: 0], [MyClass: 1]]
```

Comment: It's 2016. Use ES6.

Comment: Do not modify the prototype in the constructor!! `mc0.toString() === "[MyClass: 1]"` because you overwrote it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why the console doesn't use entered object's `toString` method?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12254038/1529630)

Comment: @K.Daniek [Just for you](https://jsfiddle.net/a4cLvmw2/)

Comment: console does not convert to string, but uses its own representation methods. Force it with `[mc0, mc1].toString()`, `[mc0, mc1].join()`, `String([mc0, mc1])`, `[mc0, mc1]+''`, or whatever else you can think of. Apply a fix for what Orial said: `this.getValue = ...etc`.

Answer (score 0):

`console.log` does not show the string representation of the object, but a tree representing its JSON notation. If you want the string representation no matter what, pass it a string.

```js
function MyClass(value) {
  this.getValue = function() { // As a side note, don't overwrite the prototype in constructor
    return value;
  }
}
MyClass.prototype.toString = function() {
    return "[MyClass: " + this.getValue() + "]";
}

var mc0 = new MyClass(0);
var mc1 = new MyClass(1);
console.log([mc0, mc1].toString());
// OR
console.log("%s",[mc0, mc1]);
```

Also, that is not the only thing `console.log` does. It also does special treatment to some objects, like DOM elements. See [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log) for details.